# Number pattern problem

Tags: pattern-recognition

I need some help to figure out the following number pattern:

Find the next number in the following sequence:
$3, 2, 3, 12, 35, 78$.

I tired to figure out the difference by add/subtract/multiple/division also tried to find the existing known pattern still could not work it out.

Comment: According to OEIS, this sequence is not listed.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, this is the first 6 values of $n$ of the sequence $n^3 - 5n^2 + 7n$

Comment: Is this a contradiction to your comment?

Comment: No. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: so the next number is 147 = 7x7x7-5x7x7+7x7

Answer (score -2):

183, because I say so.

(This makes it more than 30 characters, so there!)